# Monaca OnsenUIのボタンが消える

Tags: monaca, ios8, onsen-ui

お世話になります。

MonacaでiOSアプリの開発を行っています。

Monacaデバッガで起動した際、OnsenUIを使った以下のボタンをクリックすると、
iOS(iPad)の場合だけボタンが消えます。

押したボタンだけでなく、表示されている全てのボタンが消えます。

表示は消えますが、同じ場所をクリックすると一瞬ボタンが表示され、クリック
イベントはキックされます。

ボタンをダブルクリックのように素早くクリックすると一瞬消えますが表示が
回復します。その際のクリックイベントコードは１度しか実行されません。

Andoroid端末、PCでのプレビューでは、この現象は起きません。

何が原因でしょうか？

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">金額</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<div class="content">
    <input class="text-input" id="kingaku" ng-model="kingaku" style="text-align:right;" value="0">

    <div class="tenkey-area">
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('7');">7</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('8');">8</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('9');">9</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('4');">4</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('5');">5</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('6');">6</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('1');">1</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('2');">2</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('3');">3</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('0');">0</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('00');">00</ons-button>
        <ons-button class="tenkey" ng-click="inputKey('C');">C</ons-button><br>
        <ons-button class="tenkey regist" ng-click="setShiwake()">登録</ons-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

はむーさん
最新版のOnsen UI (1.2.2)で試したところ、ボタンが消える現象は確認できませんでした。もしかしたらレンダリングエンジンの所為で起こっている現象かもしれません。ハイパフォーマンス版でビルドして、直らないでしょうか。下記、検証に用いたコードです。

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Test</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<div class="content">
    <div>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>
        <ons-button>test</ons-button><br/>            
        <ons-button ng-click="test()">Test For Blink</ons-button>
    </div>
</div>
```